# Connecting to Red5 server from local network

Tags: java, flash, red5

I have a problem connecting to the red5 server from computers in my local network. I only can connect from the computer, where red5 server installed. I use the following link: http://my_local_ip:5080.

On the local computer, the following link works: http://localhost:5080

Where the problem may be?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your crossdomain.xml in webapps/root folder.
Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="localhost" to-ports="20-65535"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.local" to-ports="20-65535"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="20-65535"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

this is the important line:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="20-65535"/>
```

Comment: I still have the problem ?